# How to fix Mule 4 SFTP path doesn't exist error?

Tags: sftp, mule4, mule-connector

We have a Mule 4 application deployed in a Mule 4.3.0 Runtime and it's using the SFTP connector version 1.3.10 and we are getting the error `path '/source' doesn't exist`. It keeps throwing the same error until the application restarts. The error goes away after the application is restarted.
We checked with the SFTP server team they are not seeing any errors. Our code configuration looks like below

```
  <sftp:config name="SFTP_Config" doc:name="SFTP Config"
    doc:id="bed7b1d1-8f07-4e64-bb10-c4ddbd0e13ad">
    <sftp:connection host="${sftp.host}"
        port="${sftp.port}" username="${sftp.username}"
        identityFile="${sftp-keystore.location}"
        passphrase="${sftp.key.passphrase}"
        connectionTimeout="${sftp.connection-timeout.seconds}"
        responseTimeout="${sftp.response-timeout.seconds}" />
</sftp:config>

<sftp:matcher name="File_Matcher" doc:name="Matcher"
    doc:id="a214a0ce-be90-470a-a658-e506c537f0d2"
    filenamePattern="${sftp.filename.pattern}" directories="EXCLUDE" />

<until-successful
    maxRetries="${sftp.request.number-of-retry}"
    doc:name="Until Successful"
    doc:id="4b646e64-2084-43e1-b609-a49981589e34"
    millisBetweenRetries="${sftp.request.retry-interval}">
    <sftp:list doc:name="List files from SFTP"
        doc:id="61a5c497-a9bb-4c51-941c-868f8974b4f0"
        config-ref="SFTP_Config" directoryPath="${sftp.pickup.filepath}"
        matcher="File_Matcher">
        <reconnect-forever
            frequency="${sftp.reconnection.frenquency}"></reconnect-forever>
    </sftp:list>
   </until-successful>
```

Error Looks like below:

```
Root Exception stack trace:
Path '/source' doesn't exist
    at org.mule.extension.file.common.api.command.AbstractFileCommand.pathNotFoundException(AbstractFileCommand.java:176)
    at org.mule.extension.sftp.internal.command.SftpCommand.getFile(SftpCommand.java:99)
    at org.mule.extension.sftp.internal.command.SftpCommand.getExistingFile(SftpCommand.java:71)
    at org.mule.extension.sftp.internal.command.SftpListCommand.list(SftpListCommand.java:77)
    at org.mule.extension.file.common.api.AbstractFileSystem.list(AbstractFileSystem.java:112)
    at org.mule.extension.file.common.api.BaseFileSystemOperations$1.initializePagingProvider(BaseFileSystemOperations.java:149)
    at org.mule.extension.file.common.api.BaseFileSystemOperations$1.getPage(BaseFileSystemOperations.java:133)
    at org.mule.extension.file.common.api.BaseFileSystemOperations$1.getPage(BaseFileSystemOperations.java:124)
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.streaming.PagingProviderWrapper.getPage(PagingProviderWrapper.java:79)
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.streaming.PagingProviderProducer.withConnection(PagingProviderProducer.java:147)
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.streaming.PagingProviderProducer.lambda$performWithConnection$1(PagingProviderProducer.java:121)
    at net.jodah.failsafe.Functions.lambda$promiseOfStage$8(Functions.java:193)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a reconnection bug. Try with the latest of the connector, latest release of Mule and latest cumulative patch if you have the enterprise edition.